# How to debug Django unittests with PyDev?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, debugging, pydev

i've written a few unittests for a Django project. I'd like to debug them. I've set a break point on the server side. what should I click to run the Django unittest with debugging enabled in PyDev Eclipse?

It seems I can run the manage.py test command from Pydev, but then there's no debugging. If I run the unittest with right-click debug unittest, then I get all sort Internal Server errors presumably because the test envrionment wasnt set up correctly.

Comment: can you post your code since I usually do that with no error

Comment: @Hardy Do you run `django.test.TestCase` with right-click debug and it sets up the test database and the environment for you without errors and stops at breakpoints on the server side in Eclipse?

Comment: yes, unit test debug can work

Answer (score 5):

Setup a new debug configuration.

- Run -> Debug Configurations...
- Select 'PyDev Django'
- Click 'New Launch Configuration (top left corner)
- Name your new configuration
- Set the project to your project
- Set the module to your manage.py (browse to your manage.py)
- Go to the 'Arguments' tab and enter 'test' under 'Program arguments'
- Click 'Apply'

This will allow you to run 'manage.py test' and be able to stop on your breakpoints.

Unfortunately, you'll have to create different configurations if you only want to run a subset of tests.